# Is there any way to display items on listview (Android) in another way?

Tags: android, android-listview

Let's say I've got some data and they load one by one, is there any way to make every item that is added to the list view by the adapter come from the bottom of screen and then go to their original positions?

Comment: You can set animations on every item, but it will move from view's bottom not screen's bottom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :

```
list.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

It will make all the items to be added from the bottom of the list.

Comment: this just changes the order the objects are added, i want them to go up like a bubble in water from bottom of listview to previous added item

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only to change ordering? Then you should change your getView() methon in adapter, to use mirrored position in your data.

so, you should use like this

```
Type object = data.get(data.size() - position);
```